# How do I convert a project type to shared class library type

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, mapping

(C# code samples are at the bottom of the question.)

I have a class library shared between a number of solutions, with a type called `SharedType`. I have a method in the class library which processes a collection of this type:

```
Sub ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable(src As IEnumerable(Of SharedType))
    'do something here
End Sub
```

Each solution has its own specific type that should map/convert to the `SharedType`:

```
Namespace Project1
    Class ProjectType
    End Class
End Namespace
```

How can I call `ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable` without having to convert `ProjectType` to `SharedType` at the call site?

```
Dim lst As New List(Of ProjectType)
'populate list

'instead of this:
ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable(lst.Select(Function(x) New SharedType With { 'populate members here' })
'use this:
ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable(lst)
```

---

I know I can have the project type implement an interface from the class library, which has a method that maps to the shared type

```
Public Interface ISharedTypeMappable
    Function ToSharedType() As SharedType
End Interface
```

Then the `ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable` method can take `IEnumerable(Of ISharedTypeMappable)` and I can call `.Select(Function(x) x.ToSharedType)` within `ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable` to get `IEnumerable(Of SharedType)`.

---

Is there a "more correct" way to do this? Generic covariance and implicit conversion? Some .NET built-in conversion mechanism?

---

**C# code samples**

Class library method:

```
static class Utils { //I know it's an awful name ...
    static void ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable(IEnumerable<SharedType> src) {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

Project code:

```
var lst = new List<ProjectType>();
//populate list

//instead of this:
Utils.ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable(lst.Select(x=>new SharedType { /* populate properties here */}));
//do this
Utils.ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable(lst);
```

---

**Update**

I don't want to have `ProjectType` inherit from `SharedType` for two reasons (1) `ProjectType` already inherits from a different base type, and (2) `SharedType` may have members that should not be on `ProjectType`.

Comment: If you want to call that method you have to actually pass it what it expects.  You have to pass it a list of objects that ARE `SharedType`.  As such, either `SharedType` must be a class that is inherited by `ProjectType` or else it must be an interface that is implemented by `ProjectType`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ... or `ProjectType` can implement an interface which has a method to map to `SharedType`, and `ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable` can take an `IEnumerable` of said interface and use the interface method to project into an `IEnumerable(Of SharedType)`. As I wrote in the second section.

Comment: that's playing a different game though. If the method parameter is no longer type `SharedType` then it's not the same game.  My comment still stands though, i.e. you have to pass the method what it expects.  If it expects an `IEnumerable(Of SharedType)` then you have to pass an `IEnumerable(Of SharedType)` and if it expects an `IEnumerable(Of ISharedTypeMappable)` then that's what you have to pass.  It seems rather pointless to have your `ProjectType` implement some hinky interface when you could simply write a method in your project convert the data and just pass in the right type.

Comment: @jmcilhinney _"write a method in your project convert the data and just pass in the right type"_ and call this new method to map the data in every place I want to call `ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable` from the project? Defining ad implementing this interface means I never have to call the mapping code explicitly.

Comment: I can see how it might be a chore to call `ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable(myProjectTypeList.ToSharedTypeList())` instead of `ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable(myProjectTypeList)`.  Hang on, no I can't.  What you do is up to you, obviously, but your suggested solution feels architecturally wrong to me because you're putting functionality into `ProjectType` that doesn't really belong there.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Of course I name all my methods `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz` and `Baz1-100` instead of uselessly lengthy contrived names! :) Seriously, you're right, unless the functionality of the shared method should have been within `ProjectType`, if not to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance?

```
Sub Main()
    Dim lst As New List(Of ProjectType) From {
        New ProjectType With {.s = "1"},
        New ProjectType With {.s = "2"},
        New ProjectType With {.s = "3"}
    }
    SharedType.ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable(lst)
End Sub

Shared Sub ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable(src As IEnumerable(Of SharedType))
    For Each st As SharedType In src
        MsgBox(st.s)
    Next
End Sub

Class SharedType
    Property s As String
End Class

Class ProjectType
    Inherits SharedType
End Class
```

Comment: This would be the way to go, except that `ProjectType` already has a different base class than `SharedType`.

Comment: OK then, I'll revert the change. Good luck finding an answer.

Comment: `Public Shared Widening Operator CType(p As ProjectType) As SharedType` looked promising, but I couldn't get it to work in an IEnumerable

Comment: Please add the code you tried using the `Widening Operator`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is now a community wiki answer

As requested, here's my attempt at implementing `Operator Widening CType`. It does not work, though. Maybe someone reading this can work it out.

```
Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim lst As New List(Of ProjectType) From {
        New ProjectType With {.t = "1"},
        New ProjectType With {.t = "2"},
        New ProjectType With {.t = "3"}
    }
    MsgBox(CType(lst(0), SharedType).s) 'This works'
    ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable(lst) 'This does not :-( '
    ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable(lst.Cast(Of SharedType).ToList) 'Neither does this :-( '
  End Sub

  Sub ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable(src As IEnumerable(Of SharedType))
    For Each st As SharedType In src
      MsgBox(st.s)
    Next st
  End Sub

  Class SharedType
    Property s As String
  End Class

  Class ProjectType
    Property t As String

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(p As ProjectType) As SharedType
      Return New SharedType With {.s = p.t}
    End Operator
  End Class
End Module
```

Comment: Actually, that won't work if `ProcessSharedTypeEnumerable` is changing the properties of any of the `ProjectType` objects in the List. I think you'll have to put in converter functions